# text file reading and writing, ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python-3.x

I need to make a program in a single def that opens a text file 'grades' where first, last and grade are separated by comas. Each line is a separate student. Then it displays students and grades as well as class average. Then goes on to add another student and grade and saves it to the text file while including the old students. 
I guess I just don't understand the way python goes through the text file. If i comment out 'lines'  I see it prints the old_names but its as if everything is gone after. When lines is not commented out 'old_names' is not printed which makes me think the file is closed? or empty? however everything is still in the txt file as it should be.

currently i get this error.... Which I am pretty sure is telling me I'm retarded there's no information in 'line'

```
File "D:\Dropbox\Dropbox\1Python\Batch Processinga\grades.py", line 45, in main
    first_name[i], last_name[i], grades[i] = line.split(',')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

End goal is to get it to give me the current student names and grades, average. Then add one student, save that student and grade to file. Then be able to pull the file back up with all the students including the new one and do it all over again. 
I apologize for being a nub.

```
def main():
    #Declare variables
    #List of strings: first_name, last_name
    first_name = []
    last_name = []
    #List of floats: grades
    grades = []
    #Float grade_avg, new_grade
    grade_avg = new_grade = 0.0
    #string new_student
    new_student = ''


    #Intro
    print("Program displays information from a text file to")
    print("display student first name, last name, grade and")
    print("class average then allows user to enter another")
    print("student.\t")

    #Open file “grades.txt” for reading
    infile = open("grades.txt","r")

    lines = infile.readlines()

    old_names = infile.read()
    print(old_names)

    #Write for loop for each line creating a list
    for i in len(lines):
         #read in line
         line = infile.readline()

         #Split data
         first_name[i], last_name[i], grades[i] = line.split(',')

         #convert grades to floats
         grades[i] = float(grades[i])

    print(first_name, last_name, grades)
    #close the file
    infile.close()

    #perform calculations for average
    grade_avg = float(sum(grades)/len(grades))


    #display results
    print("Name\t\t Grade")
    print("----------------------")
    for n in range(5):
        print(first_name[n], last_name[n], "\t", grades[n])

    print('')
    print('Average Grade:\t% 0.1f'%grade_avg)

    #Prompt user for input of new student and grade
    new_student = input('Please enter the First and Last name of new student:\n').title()
    new_grade = eval(input("Please enter {}'s grade:".format(new_student)))

    #Write new student and grade to grades.txt in same format as other records
    new_student = new_student.split()
    new_student = str(new_student[1] + ',' + new_student[0] + ',' + str(new_grade))

    outfile = open("grades.txt","w")

    print(old_names, new_student ,file=outfile)

    outfile.close()enter code here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File objects in Python have a "file pointer", which keeps track of what data you've already read from the file. It uses this to know where to start looking when you call `read` or `readline` or `readlines`. Calling `readlines` moves the file pointer all the way to the end of the file; subsequent read calls will return an empty string. This explains why you're getting a ValueError on the `line.split(',')` line. `line` is an empty string, so `line.split(",")` returns a list of length 0, but you need a list of length 3 to do the triple assignment you're attempting.

Once you get the `lines` list, you don't need to interact with the `infile` object any more. You already have all the lines; you may as well simply iterate through them directly.

```
#Write for loop for each line creating a list
for line in lines:
    columns = line.split(",")
    first_name.append(columns[0])
    last_name.append(columns[1])
    grades.append(float(columns[2]))
```

Note that I'm using `append` instead of `listName[i] = whatever`. This is necessary because Python lists will not automatically resize themselves when you try to assign to an index that doesn't exist yet; you'll just get an `IndexError`. `append`, on the other hand, will resize the list as desired.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is spot on i may need to read it a few more times but i get it. Now if i could just get the file to write the old_names in the text file how they were and not like this....['Mickey,Mouse,90\n', 'Jane,Doe,50\n', 'Minnie,Mouse,95\n', 'Donald,Duck,80\n', 'Daffy,Duck,70\n'] Lars,Olrich,69